# PHP use one central variables file inside functions

Tags: php

In PHP, what is the right way forward for the following situation:

I have a 'central' vars.php which contains some parameters like MySQL hostname, user, pass, a $Test variable which indicates if the code is running in a test environment or not, and some other variables which I use throughout my site.

Then I have a functions.php which contains all the functions I could use throughout my site.

In some of these functions, I might need some the variables out of the vars.php file.

What is the right way to make the vars.php available to 'everywhere' in PHP?
Now I am doing it like this:

```
vars.php:
   <?php
   if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"localhost"))
   {
       $Test = true;
   }
   ?>

functions.php:
   <?php
   function DoSomething()
   {
      include "vars.php";
      if($Test)
      {
         $String = "Test is true!";
      }
         else
         {
            $String = "Test is false!";
         }
      return $String;
   }
   ?>

index.php:
   <?php
   include "vars.php";
   include "functions.php;
   $DoSomething = DoSomething();
   echo $DoSomething;
   ?>
```

While this does work, I have to include the vars.php in each function I define, this doesn't seem like a 'nice' solution to me.
Isn't there a way to define the variables in vars.php directly in the global scope, and be able to use them inside functions directly without having to worry about including them?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you might want to use include_once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use constants. Define all together and always on top of classes/files.

Constants are uniques and we use them as config info or static/const data.

If u are sue DEFINE remember use const as a string not a var, example:

define("BASE_PATH", "C://base/");

$dir = BASE_PATH . "images/dropbox.txt";

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Comment: Giving additional info such as why you're linking that would help, just pasting a link is usually not as helpful as full explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The right way would be using constants instead of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for global variables. If you include the file at the top of your page and then declare each one as a global within your function like this:

```
include('vars.php');


function whatHost()
{
  global $host;
  echo $host;
}
```

it will work. This is very bad practice though, as global state is very bad 95% of the time. PHP has powerful object-oriented features which allow you to encapsulate functionality and state within objects. I suggest you read up on that and learn about more proper ways of storing application configuration. Note that for this particular situation, you could just use constants (: